# How can i make as proper Q&A in jsp from this table?

Tags: java, html, jsp

i want to generate question and answer from the oracle database and sort them in proper question and answer for the objective question?

controller code

```
public ArrayList<DOWNLOAD_SUB> getQUESTION_SUB2() throws SQLException{
                ArrayList<DOWNLOAD_SUB> question_subssss = new ArrayList<>();

                Connection connection = fACADE.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT A.QUESTION, B.ANSWER FROM QUESTION_OBJ A, OBJ_ANSWER B WHERE A.QUESTION_OBJ_ID = B.QUESTION_OBJ_ID");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){

                    DOWNLOAD_SUB question_sub1=new DOWNLOAD_SUB();

                    question_sub1.setQUESTION(rs.getString(1));
                    question_sub1.setANSWER(rs.getString(2));
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

                    question_subssss.add(question_sub1);

                }
                return question_subssss;

            }
```

jsp file- this is normal table that repeated the same question, i don't know how to make as proper Q&A without using this table

```
<table class="table" border=2 bgcolor="white">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>QUESTION</th>
                <th>AWNSER</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%
                            for (DOWNLOAD_SUB fquestion_sub : DOWNLOAD_SUB2) 
                            {
                        %>

                <tr>

                    <td><%=fquestion_sub.getQUESTION()%></td>
                    <td><%=fquestion_sub.getANSWER()%></td>

                </tr>


                <%
                            }
                        %>
```

the result is

```
           QUESTION                                             |ANSWER
WHAT ARE THE MOLECULE STATE THAT OCCUR DURING HIGH PRESSURE?    |IRON
WHAT ARE THE MOLECULE STATE THAT OCCUR DURING HIGH PRESSURE?    |GAS STATE
WHAT ARE THE MOLECULE STATE THAT OCCUR DURING HIGH PRESSURE?    |LIQUID
WHAT ARE THE MOLECULE STATE THAT OCCUR DURING HIGH PRESSURE?    |SOLID
```

what i need is

```
 1)WHAT ARE THE MOLECULE STATE THAT OCCUR DURING HIGH PRESSURE?

 A. IRON
 B. GAS STATE
 C. LIQUID
 D. SOLID
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming DOWNLOAD_SUB2 is single question with multiple choice

```
<%=DOWNLOAD_SUB2.get(0).getQUESTION()%>
<ol type="A">
<%    for (DOWNLOAD_SUB fquestion_sub : DOWNLOAD_SUB2)  {  %>
   <li><%=fquestion_sub.getANSWER()%></li>
<% } %>
</ol>
```

Instead of using HTML Table tags, you can use Ordered list tags `<ol>` and `<li>`

Ideally your data structure should be a `Map<String, List<String>>` where key in the Map is the question, and list is the multiple choices.

Comment: The question is repeating because of the array from one to many table..how to display just one question?

Answer (score 0):

Create an ordered list of ordered lists of type="A"

```
<!-- Open the question list -->
<ol> 
    // Add your For loop here...
    <li>
        <p>WHAT ARE THE MOLECULE STATE THAT OCCUR DURING HIGH PRESSURE?</p>
        <!-- Open the answer list -->
        <ol type="A"> 
            <li>IRON</li>
            <li>GAS STATE</li>
            <li>LIQUID</li>
            <li>SOLID</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    // End your loop here...
</ol>
```

This will output:
    1. WHAT ARE THE MOLECULE STATE THAT OCCUR DURING HIGH PRESSURE?

```
    A. IRON
    B. GAS STATE
    C. LIQUID
    D. SOLID
```

Comment: I'm using this but the question just display 1 answer and repeated same question with next answer.. <ol>
   <%
                            for (DOWNLOAD_SUB fquestion_sub : DOWNLOAD_SUB2) 
                            {
                        %>
   <li>
    <p><%=fquestion_sub.getQUESTION()%></p> <!-- Open the answer list -->
    <ol type="A">
     <li><%=fquestion_sub.getANSWER()%></li>

    </ol>
   </li>
   <%
                            }
                        %>
  </ol>

Comment: Each answer returned by `fquestion_sub.getANSWER()` method needs to be wrapped in `<li>` tags. So if `.getANSWER()` is returning a string, add the opening / closing `<li>` tags between each answer. Otherwise, if it's one by one or an array, implement a for loop similar to sidgate's answer above.